# Enable .NET Core collection in AppService with ARM or PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell

I would like to enable the .NET Core collection level with applicationInsight in Azure AppService as shown in below picture. From Azure Portal it works well. Keep in mind that by default value is set to disabled:

[image]

Now I would like to automate this using either ARM template or powershell.

- I did a export template to see how it looks on ARM but there is no settings related to .NET Core collection
- I check documentation on MS website but nothing about ARM template with enabling collection too
- In PowerShell same problem

Is there anyone in the community who know how to enable the collection using ARM or PowerShell ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's simply setting an app setting called `XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_Mode` with value `recommended` (to enable) or `default` (to disable) as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-monitor/app/azure-web-apps?tabs=netcore#application-settings-definitions). You can do that both in ARM or PowerShell as below.

### ARM (check `appSettings` part):

```
{
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "[parameters('name')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "properties": {
                "siteConfig": {
                    "appSettings": [
                        {
                            "name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",
                            "value": "[reference('microsoft.insights/components/AppMonitoredSite', '2015-05-01').InstrumentationKey]"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING",
                            "value": "[reference('microsoft.insights/components/AppMonitoredSite', '2015-05-01').ConnectionString]"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION",
                            "value": "~2"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_Mode ",
                            "value": "recommended"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "name": "[parameters('name')]",
                "serverFarmId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', parameters('subscriptionId'),'/resourcegroups/', parameters('serverFarmResourceGroup'), '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]",
                "hostingEnvironment": "[parameters('hostingEnvironment')]"
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('hostingPlanName'))]",
                "microsoft.insights/components/AppMonitoredSite"
            ],
            "apiVersion": "2016-03-01",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]"
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
            "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "name": "[parameters('hostingPlanName')]",
                "workerSizeId": "[parameters('workerSize')]",
                "numberOfWorkers": "1",
                "hostingEnvironment": "[parameters('hostingEnvironment')]"
            },
            "sku": {
                "Tier": "[parameters('sku')]",
                "Name": "[parameters('skuCode')]"
            }
        },
        {
            "apiVersion": "2015-05-01",
            "name": "AppMonitoredSite",
            "type": "microsoft.insights/components",
            "location": "West US 2",
            "properties": {
                "ApplicationId": "[parameters('name')]",
                "Request_Source": "IbizaWebAppExtensionCreate"
            }
        }
    ],
    "parameters": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "hostingPlanName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "hostingEnvironment": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "sku": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "skuCode": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "workerSize": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "serverFarmResourceGroup": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "subscriptionId": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01-preview/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
}
```

### Powershell:

```
$app = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName "AppMonitoredRG" -Name "AppMonitoredSite" -ErrorAction Stop
$newAppSettings = @{} # case-insensitive hash map
$app.SiteConfig.AppSettings | %{$newAppSettings[$_.Name] = $_.Value} # preserve non Application Insights application settings.
$newAppSettings["APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"] = "012345678-abcd-ef01-2345-6789abcd"; # set the Application Insights instrumentation key
$newAppSettings["APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"] = "InstrumentationKey=012345678-abcd-ef01-2345-6789abcd"; # set the Application Insights connection string
$newAppSettings["ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION"] = "~2"; # enable the ApplicationInsightsAgent
$newAppSettings["XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_Mode"] = "recommended"; # set the APM collection to recommended
$app = Set-AzWebApp -AppSettings $newAppSettings -ResourceGroupNamrecommendede $app.ResourceGroup -Name $app.Name -ErrorAction Stop
```

Comment: Thx KrishG for your valuable help and time you took to give all these precision. I do confirm it helps me a lot. I miss the documentation about the parameter XDT_MicrosoftApplicationInsights_Mode .